# Lim sup and Borel-Cantelli solution

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

I was seeking a solution to a textbook's problem to check if mine is correct and found one that got me a doubt.

> We'd like to show that:
>
> \begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\left( \frac{|X_{n}|}{n}>1 \right) < \infty \implies \lim \sup_{n}\frac{|X_{n}|}{n}\leq 1\end{align}

My first thought was applying Borel-Cantelli lemma, so we show that it will be higher than 1 infinitely often with probability $0$.

The author did the above and proceeded with the following step:

$\mathbb{P}\left(\lim \sup \left[ \frac{|X_{n}|}{n}>1 \right]\right) = 0 \implies \mathbb{P}\left(\lim \sup \left[ \frac{|X_{n}|}{n} \leq 1\right]\right) = 1$

Is this because we know the following from the series?

$\mathbb{P}\left( \frac{|X_{n}|}{n}>1 \right) \downarrow 0 \implies\mathbb{P}\left( \left[\frac{|X_{n}|}{n}>1\right]^{c} \right) =  \mathbb{P}\left( \frac{|X_{n}|}{n}\leq1 \right) \uparrow 1$

And thus a series based upon the complement sequence won't converge atributing probability $1$ to $\lim \sup_{n}\frac{|X_{n}|}{n}\leq 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the sum is zero, then each term is zero, which implies that $P(|X_n|/n > 1) = 0$ for any $n$. So $P(|X_n|/n \leq 1) = 1$. Since the statement holds for all $n$, the countable intersection of these probability $1$ events still has probability $1$, and so 
\begin{align*}
P\left(\bigcap_n \{|X_n|/n \leq 1\}\right) = 1
\end{align*}
Hence $\limsup |X_n|/n \leq 1$ with probability $1$.

Comment: I'm really sorry, sum = 0 was a typo.

Comment: Then $P(\limsup X_n/n > 1) \leq P(X/n > 1 \text{ i.o.}) = 0$ by the first Borel Cantelli Lemma